# Changelistener for BufferedImage

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage, changelistener

Is there a way to track changes in the pixel data of a BufferdImage?
I was thinking about something like that:

```
PixelChangeListener listener = new PixelChangeListener() {
public void pixelchange(Event e) {
    // Get the coordinates in the Image that have been changed:
    int x=e.getX();
    int y=e.getY();
}
};
buffimage.addPixelChangeListener(listener);
```

If i now use `g.drawLine` or `buffimage.setRGB(x,y,rgb);` `pixelchange(e)` should fire.
Is there a way to do that? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't such a listener. But you could extend `BufferedImage` and add the APIs you need.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) unfortunately it only tracks `setRGB()` . i dont know why, but Graphics methods do not use `setRGB()` to render. Do I have to extend `Graphics` too?

Comment: No, you don't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

*This is the solution from the OP (which was originally posted right in the question).*

---

Not the BufferedImage itself but the WritableRaster behind it had to be modified.
You can use `sun.awt.image.SunWritableRaster` for that, just use the `notifychanged()` 
method to track pixelchanges.
To get a proper BufferedImage with the Raster I used this code:

```
ColorModel colormodel=ColorModel.getRGBdefault();
WritableRaster temp=colormodel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(400,400);
SunWritableRaster raster=new SunWritableRaster(temp.getSampleModel(),temp.getDataBuffer(),new Point(0,0));
BufferedImage img=new BufferedImage(colormodel,raster,true,null);
```